# Missing Request Body using Guzzle 6 in Laravel 5.7 working over Sage API 3.1

Tags: laravel, guzzle6

According to the SAGE API 3.1 [manual](https://developer.sage.com/api/accounting/docs/concepts/invoicing.html), to create an invoice you must pass the following:

```
POST /sales_invoices
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*

{
  "sales_invoice": {
    "contact_id": "14d93840783b11e8990a122c8428e4b2",
    "date": "2018-06-24",
    "invoice_lines": [
      {
        "description": "A Minimal Invoice Item",
        "ledger_account_id": "4195173e75db11e8990a122c8428e4b2",
        "quantity": "1",
        "unit_price": "0.99",
        "tax_rate_id": "584793ca75db11e8990a122c8428e4b2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Well, On my code

```
$client = new Client();

$endpoint = $this->endpoint.'/'.$this->action; // https://api.accounting.sage.com/v3.1/sales_invoices

$response = $client->post($endpoint, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->token // My token valid
                ],
                'form_params' => $this->params
            ]);
```

My params

```
"sales_invoice" => array:3 [
    "contact_id" => "a39b46d1cb8a4f5a9048c32f7895147c"
    "date" => "2018-03-04"
    "invoice_lines" => array:1 [
      0 => array:5 [
        "description" => "Factura creada por error"
        "ledger_account_id" => "49131457ee4f11e8ae720268dc652fba"
        "quantity" => "1"
        "unit_price" => "0"
        "tax_rate_id" => "ES_EXEMPT"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

And Guzzle extended error show problems in `sales_invoice[invoice_lines]` that missings values.

```
[{
    "$severity": "error",
    "$dataCode": "Validation",
    "$message": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines] is invalid",
    "$source": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines]"
}, {
    "$severity": "error",
    "$dataCode": "Validation",
    "$message": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines] is invalid",
    "$source": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines]"
}, {
    "$severity": "error",
    "$dataCode": "Validation",
    "$message": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines] is invalid",
    "$source": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines]"
}, {
    "$severity": "error",
    "$dataCode": "Validation",
    "$message": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines][0][description] is missing",
    "$source": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines][0][description]"
}, {
    "$severity": "error",
    "$dataCode": "Validation",
    "$message": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines][0][ledger_account_id] is missing",
    "$source": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines][0][ledger_account_id]"
}, {
    "$severity": "error",
    "$dataCode": "Validation",
    "$message": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines][0][unit_price] is missing",
    "$source": "sales_invoice[invoice_lines][0][unit_price]"
}]
```

What is wrong on this code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending it via `form_params`, send the payload as `json`:

```
$response = $client->post($endpoint, [
    'headers' => [
         'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->token // My token valid
    ],
    'json' => $this->params
]);
```

> The content type header `application/json` is added automatically.

Comment: Thank s. Incredible. Now error demmand a `main_address`but API show this it's not required. ` Client error: `POST https://api.accounting.sage.com/v3.1/sales_invoices` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:
[{"$severity":"error","$dataCode":"RecordInvalid","$message":"This field is required.","$source":"main_address"}]`